# 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<ObjectModel>'

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to display this data that im pulling from a query , I keep on getting the error

> 'MappedListIterable<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type
> 'FutureOr'

how can i go about fixing this :

```
 Future<ObjectModel> getObjectById(String ID) async {
    final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(API.getObjectByID));
    final object = jsonDecode(res.body);

    print(object);
    return object.map((e) => ObjectModel.fromJson(e));
  }
```

this snippet of code containes `fromJson()` part of my data model for the sake of context :

```
factory ObjectModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return ObjectModel(
      objectID: json['objectID'] ?? '' ,
      objectName: json['objectName'] ?? '' ,
      objectPrice: json['objectPrice']?? '',
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you include your `fromJson`

Comment: what do you mean , should i include the data model ?

Comment: yes, that will be better,

Comment: okay cool pls check out updated query

Comment: Can you share the printed `object` as well

Comment: printed object  just displays the values from api

Comment: Yap try my post, if fails consider including that part

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `object.map((e) => ObjectModel.fromJson(e))`  if the response is already a formatted map based on the model.

```dart
 Future<ObjectModel?> getObjectById(String ID) async {
  try{
    final res = await http.get(Uri.parse(API.getObjectByID));
    final object = jsonDecode(res.body);
    return  ObjectModel.fromJson(object); //which is fromMap as you've defined
    }
    catch (e){
      debugPrint(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: so how can i then map values from the object variable , the object essentially stores values from the api , ObjectModel is the data model ?

Comment: You've already done that part `fromJson`, consider including response data if something fails

Comment: mymistake, that will be object